# How can Instagram cause Chrome to attempt to login and show me my username when I'm using incognito mode?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, javascript, chrome, html

When I reach Instagram user pages while in Incognito mode, Chrome pops up a window with my non-incognito username asking whether or not to sign in. See screenshot below. Although I assume Chrome Incognito isn't broken and sharing this information with Instagram - I do wonder how Instagram caused this dialog to show. It is a bit intrusive and I would have preferred if Chrome didn't do this. I've also never seen it anywhere on the internet, so it is a bit of a head scratcher. How'd they do it?

[image]

Comment: Being able to use saved pw in incognito is a feature not a bug (as look as it's never done w/o user input).

Answer (score 3):

**Instagram** can't, and isn't, doing that. [Chrome is](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?hl=en&visit_id=636977886281535670-3428507219&rd=1). Chrome knows your Google account because you've signed in to it, and they know that you have your Instagram credentials saved in your Google account, so when you visit the Instagram website, they offer to sign in automatically for you. <del>I don't know why this would trigger in Incognito mode; that seems like a possible bug.</del> [This is by design](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=864381&can=1&q=component%3APrivacy%3EIncognito&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), apparently. I find this a bit worrying.

This popup isn't disableable as far as I can tell. You can only control whether sign-in occurs automatically, or requires a prompt ("Auto Sign-in" in `chrome://settings/passwords`). If you're getting the prompt, it means you've disabled auto sign-in; that's as good as Chrome will give you, unless I'm missing an additional setting.

Comment: No other site exhibits any behavior like this. So I have to assume Instagram is doing something to cause it.

Comment: According to [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=864381&can=1&q=component%3APrivacy%3EIncognito&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) bug report, this is by design. Chrome will offer to sign in with saved credentials while in incognito mode.

Comment: @ubershmekel Yes, Instagram and some other services basically say "Browser, if your user has credentials, ask them to log in." Chrome then displays this dialogue to you. Instagram does not get any information about credentials unless you log in with them.

Comment: The reason why Chrome offers this is because people have a wrong perception of incognito mode. The idea is that things you do in incognito mode should not affect the "regular browsing", such as creating cookies, browser history, etc. The normal browsing can (and does) affect browsing in incognito mode.

Comment: @ubershmekel I've seen this same behavior on many sites, and this is the reason it happens.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: @AlphaD ...I hope I'm not the only one who finds that a bit disquieting. I typically use Incognito mode to (help) _avoid_ being tracked; logging in would mean being tracked again. Anyway, thanks for the update. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: In incognito, all pw forms are proposing me autofill with saved pw from my account; proposing not doing it implicitly.

Comment: The bug link is useful but doesn't answer the question. I would accept the answer if it were to explain how the "Sign in as" pop-up is triggered. Other sites do allow me to autofill username and password. But I'm unfamiliar with a mechanism that triggers the dialog in the screenshot.

Comment: @ubershmekel This is just part of Google's identity platform. Not sure what else you want, as there's... nothing else. Chrome detects that you have a saved login for that site and offers to log you in to it. I've edited my answer to clarify (because, technically, you're not signing in with _your Google account_, you're signing in with _credentials saved in your Google account_, which might have been the source of confusion...) but that's... all there is. Instagram doesn't "trigger" anything. Like I said. If you refuse to accept a complete answer, I'm not particularly bothered.